# How to handle large image files in file input JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, canvas

i have image file to upload into my react apps.

image =

size: 28mb

resolution: 8xxx x 12xxx

```
onFileChange(e){
  const imageFile = e.target.files[0]
  const imageBase64 = fileToBase64(imageFile)
  let img = new Image()
  img.onload = () => {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

    // crop process ... (vanilla js)

    canvas.drawImage(...)
    return canvas.toDataURL()
  }
  img.src = imageBase64
}
```

my react apps always glitch when drawImage.
sometimes crash the tab browser

tried in :

- macOS : chrome displaying "something went wrong while displaying this webpage"

- windows 10 : chrome glitch while load the image and displaying black image on canvas

or, any limit size for load image in javascript / canvas / others ?

Comment: _“size: 28mb”_ - mostly irrelevant, the important part is _“resolution: 8xxx x 12xxx”_ - so that is at least 96,000,000 pixels, times three for RGB is 288,000,000 bytes, or ~ 275 MB your browser has to handle in memory, to draw the image onto the canvas.

Comment: @CBroe any idea ? i didn't want to decrease the quality of image file.

Comment: Why is this using canvas, are you trying to display the image to the user before the upload? Without that part, this would probably work a lot smoother - because then the browser would only have to handle the 28 MB of actual file size.

Comment: @CBroe trying to put the image onto canvas process was my process to crop the image and return base64 string, then send to the server. but when the canvas draw image after crop process, it always glitch the tab screen

Comment: The code you had shown doesn’t do any cropping. There probably isn’t a real solution to this then, cropping kinda needs the canvas. You could only upload the full image first, without canvas, and do the cropping on the server side. But then you’d probably have to implement a different UI for the cropping somehow …

Comment: @CBroe i was edit the question. that case shows i want to crop the image on client-side, thank you for your support